# How to change the colour of an object randomly every second in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

It's working now. This is the correct code. InvokeRepeating takes 3 arguments.
[I added the colors i needed and selected my mesh renderer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7POO.png)

```
using UnityEngine;

public class colorchange : MonoBehaviour {

    public Color []colors;
    public Renderer rendering;

    void Start () 
    {
        InvokeRepeating ("ChangeColor", 0f, 1f);
    }

    void ChangeColor()
    {
        rendering.material.color = colors[Random.Range(0, colors.Length -1)];
    }

}
```

Comment: Dont change your question for an answer. This is now useless to anyone who'd be looking for something similar.

Comment: Ok. So do I need to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public Renderer renderer;

void Start()
{
     InvokeRepeating("ChangeColor", 1.0f, 1.0f);
}

void ChangeColor()
{
     renderer.material.color = new Color(Random.Range(0f,1f), Random.Range(0f,1f),  Random.Range(0f,1f), 1.0f);
}
```

One major issue is that it will give really "ugly" color in many occasions. So you'd be better off with a collection of color to choose from:

```
public Color []colors;
public Renderer renderer;

void Start()
{
     InvokeRepeating("ChangeColor", 1.0f, 1.0f);
}

void ChangeColor()
{
     renderer.material.color = colors[Random.Range(0, colors.Length -1)];
}
```

Some info source to look at:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-material.html

Comment: It shows this now. No overload for method 'InvokeRepeating' takes 2 arguments

Answer (score -1):

- You have to get the renderer component and use that to change it's material (rather than statically accessing the 'Renderer' class which will no work for your purpose).
- When creating the new random color, you have to assign it to a variable, in your case 'newColor' because currently this variable doesn't exists in your script.
- Random.value isn't a thing :)

The following code uses a property block to change the color of the renderer's material, avoiding the creation of a new material (for better performance, and I think better practice).

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(Renderer)]
public class ColorChange : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float _changeColorAfterSeconds = 1f;

    private Renderer _renderer;
    private float _timer = 0f;

    private MaterialPropertyBlock _block;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        _block    = new MaterialPropertyBlock();
    }
    
    private void Update ()
    {
        _timer += Time.deltaTime;

        if (_timer >= _changeColorAfterSeconds) 
        {
            Color newColor = new Color(Random.Range(0f, 1f),
                                       Random.Range(0f, 1f),
                                       Random.Range(0f, 1f),
                                       1f);

            _block.SetColor("_Color", newColor);
            _renderer.SetPropertyBlock(_block);

            _timer = 0f;
        }
    }
}
```

To simply fix your script / make it work as is:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class colorchange : MonoBehaviour {

    private float timer = 0f;

    void Update () {
        
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        if (timer >= 1f) 
        {
            Color newColor = new Color(Random.Range(0f, 1f), Random.Range(0f, 1f), Random.Range(0f, 1f), 1.0f);

            GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = newColor;
            timer = 0f;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It shows 'UnityEngine.Color' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'